# Is a constant electric field CP violating?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electric-fields, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory, cp-violation

Consider, for instance, a fundamental massless three-form field $C_{\alpha\beta\gamma}$ in the Coulomb phase:

$$
\mathcal L = E_{\mu\alpha\beta\gamma}E^{\mu\alpha\beta\gamma} + C_{\alpha\beta\gamma}J^{\alpha\beta\gamma}\,,
$$

where $E_{\mu\alpha\beta\gamma} = \partial_{[\mu}C_{\alpha\beta\gamma]}$ is the field strength and $J^{\alpha\beta\gamma}$ is a conserved external current.

In the absence of sources, the four-form electric field can take an arbitrary constant value, $E_{\mu\alpha\beta\gamma} = E_0\epsilon_{\mu\alpha\beta\gamma}$ with $E_0$ a constant number.

In a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0507215) by Gia Dvali, it is claimed that

> Any theory in which a three-form field is in the Coulomb phase ‘suffers’ from a generalized strong CP problem.

I would like to know why a constant electric field violates CP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because $E$ is a **psuedo-scalar**.

$E$ is a 4-form, which in 4-d is a *volume form*. Hence under a transformation $T^\mu_\nu$ it goes to $\det(T) E$. This makes it Lorenz invariant since Lorenz transformations have determinant 1, but not $P$ invariant since $\det(P)=-1$. Since we also expect $C$ to act trivially on $E$, we have $CP(E)=-E$.